# Add shared libraries references to enterprise applications whith Jython in Websphere application server

Tags: shared-libraries, jython, application-server, websphere-7

I would like to programmatically add the shared libraries to my deployed applications in websphere application server (WAS).

I heard that it is possible using **jython** scripting.

How can I achieve this?

Can someone give some pratical example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with the following script:

```
# Map shared library 
AdminApp.edit('ApplicationName', ['-MapSharedLibForMod', [['.*', '.*', 'SharedLibName']]])

# Save configuration
AdminConfig.save()

# Synchronize nodes (if you don't have standalone server but network deployment)
Sync1 = AdminControl.completeObjectName('type=NodeSync,node=*,*')
AdminControl.invoke(Sync1, 'sync')
```

I am using this method and it works.